# saving h264 file in JAVA works, but in android it saves corrupted file

Tags: java, android, video, h.264

I am trying to save a stream of bytes in h264 format, to an h264 file.
I did it in JAVA, and the file is being saved and I can open it and see the video.
BUT, when I try the exact same code, in android, and I'm trying to save the file through the android device, the file is corrupted.
This is my code (both for android and for java):

```
    File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
    File file = new File(path, "/" + "filename2.mp4");
    FileOutputStream output2 = null;
    try {
        output2 = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
        output2.write(my_stream.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            output2.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

- offcourse just the path is different in java and in the android version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because my_stream.toByteArray() is only one part of the whole video. Read the video stream in a loop and write it to the output stream chunk by chunk.

Alternatively there is this function that will do it for you:

```
Files.copy(videoInputStream, filePath, StandardCopyOptions.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Or if the input is a byte array:

```
Files.write(outputPath, bytes, StandardOpenOptions.WRITE, 
    StandardOpenOptions.CREATE_NEW, 
    StandardOpenOptions.CREATE);
```

Full documentation: [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,%20byte[],%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,%20byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...))

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html

Comment: my video stream is in type of `byte[]` and not an `inputStream` type, so this method doesn't work for me

Comment: Is it just one byte array or a stream of byte arrays? I've updated the answer for byte array

Comment: still having some troubles... in this case how can I declare the path? currently I'm creating it from a file a not a path object, and, I getting every second a new frame, so I need to append to this file the frames bytes[], and not create a new file every time.

Comment: It is possible to create a path object from string or use the one you get from Enviroment. I've linked you the documentation. It explains how to append bytes or creating a new file when not exist using different combinations of StandardOpenOptions